# Asterisk and AMI Originate extension is not busy

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

In Asterisk in the initiation of the call through the AMI interface if extension is busy (talking), the call doesn't bounce. If on softphone enabled DND mode, or hang up manually(by press red button on softphone), it bounces, as necessary:

```
 -- Called 198
-- SIP/198-00000d90 is busy

Action:Originate
ActionID:1234
Channel:SIP/198
Context:from-internal
Priority:1
Exten:0991112233
Async:false
CallerId:obzvon
Timeout:30000
```

Asterisk 12.5.0, FreePBX 12.0.7.

Common Freepbx dialplan without customizations.

CallWaiting Disable

Put in "Context: default" - no result.

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That mean phone(NOT asterisk) for some reason return busy.

No way say "why" based on info provided.

Can suggest enable sip debug, dial as Local/198@from-internal/n

ps debug is offtopic on SO